# Cannot call Element Props inside React Navigation Stack.Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using React-Navigation v5 with Redux. I like to call my logOut action creator to trigger my log out function from my headerRight.

However, I can only access logOut from inside Home element and not inside HomeStack.

One idea I have is to also wrap my HomeStack with connect. I haven't tried it yet to know whether it can work or not. Even should it work, this isn't my preferred solution because i feel it makes my code very verbose

Anyone has a solution on how to access my logOut function from within my HomeStack? Thanks in advance

```
    const Home = props => {
  const { loading, error, data, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(FIND_BOOKS_QUERY);
  console.log("home props", props);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Welcome {props.user && props.user.name} </Text>
      {loading && <Text>Loading...</Text>}
      {error && <Text>Error: {error.message}</Text>}
      {data &&
        data.findBooks.map((x, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text>
                {x.title} - {x.author}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeContainer = connect(
  state => {
    // console.log("home state", state);
    return {
      user: state.auth.user
    };
  },
  { logOut }
)(Home);

export const HomeStack = props => {
  console.log("home stack props", props);
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeContainer}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
              // props.logOut // - cannot access logOut here as HomeStack props does not have logOut
                  console.log("exit");
                }}
              >
                <Text>Exit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping my HomeStack with connect works. Its able to make available logOut inside H which allows me to call logOut inside headerRight.

However, such a method will be verbose because I will need to connect both H and Home to redux. Is there a more elegant way? Thanks

```
const Home = props => {
  const { loading, error, data, subscribeToMore } = useQuery(FIND_BOOKS_QUERY);
  console.log("home props", props);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> Welcome {props.user && props.user.name} </Text>
      {loading && <Text>Loading...</Text>}
      {error && <Text>Error: {error.message}</Text>}
      {data &&
        data.findBooks.map((x, index) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text>
                {x.title} - {x.author}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeContainer = connect(
  state => {
    // console.log("home state", state);
    return {
      user: state.auth.user
    };
  },
  { logOut }
)(Home);

export const H = props => {
  console.log("home stack props", props);
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeContainer}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  props.logOut(); // now works OK
                  console.log("exit");
                }}
              >
                <Text>Exit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const HomeStack = connect(
  state => {
    // console.log("home state", state);
    return {
      user: state.auth.user
    };
  },
  { logOut }
)(H);
```